# Is there any way to change the font of my IDE? (RAD Studio 10.4)

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.4.2

is there any way to change the font? I would like to put a nicer one but I can't change it, just let me modify the colors

Comment: Are you referring to the font of the source editor or the IDE itself?

Comment: For reference, Delphi comes with [extensive documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Main_Page).  Most questions such as these are [covered sufficiently](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Display) there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the editor font and size in the Options menu.

[image: Options menu]

From Help:

> Select a font type from the available screen fonts installed on your system (shown in the list). The Code Editor displays and uses only monospaced screen fonts, such as Courier.

For code, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num +</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num -</kbd> to increase and decrease the font size.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. 

Can I add even more fonts?

Comment: From Help `Select a font type from the available screen fonts installed on your system (shown in the list). The Code Editor displays and uses only monospaced screen fonts, such as Courier. `

Comment: @Julian so the answer looks like is yes, based on the help file, but only if the font is monospaced.

Comment: Note that Delphi 11 offers to install additional fonts suitable for the source code editor. These can even be used with Delphi 10.4 then.

Comment: It worked perfect, I was able to leave a nice font in my IDE, thank you very much!